# Searching for hardcode in python with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, sonarqube

I would like to find hardcoded strings like emails, paths or servernames (in this example just emails) in a bunch of python modules. 
I tried to check all dictionaries, lists and attributes, if they're contain "mail" inside and then checked if they contain strings. Although I get all hardcoded mails, I also get mailList, which are not hardcoded, but have qoutes in the line.

```
//TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR[contains(@tokenValue,"mail")]/..//STRING[contains(@tokenValue,"'")]
```

Here is a xml sample, which is parsed from a python module:

```
<FILE_INPUT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
  <STATEMENT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
    <STMT_LIST tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
      <SIMPLE_STMT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
        <IMPORT_STMT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
          <IMPORT_NAME tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0">
            <IMPORT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="0"/>
            <DOTTED_AS_NAMES tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="7">
              <DOTTED_AS_NAME tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="7">
                <DOTTED_NAME tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="7">
                  <NAME tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="7">
                    <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="7"/>
                  </NAME>
                </DOTTED_NAME>
              </DOTTED_AS_NAME>
            </DOTTED_AS_NAMES>
          </IMPORT_NAME>
        </IMPORT_STMT>
      </SIMPLE_STMT>
    </STMT_LIST>
    <NEWLINE tokenValue="
" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="12"/>
  </STATEMENT>
  <STATEMENT tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
    <STMT_LIST tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
      <SIMPLE_STMT tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
        <EXPRESSION_STMT tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
            <TEST tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
              <ATOM tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
                <NAME tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0">
                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="serverList" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="0"/>
                </NAME>
              </ATOM>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
          <ASSIGN tokenValue="=" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="11"/>
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="[" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="13">
            <TEST tokenValue="[" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="13">
              <ATOM tokenValue="[" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="13">
                <LBRACKET tokenValue="[" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="13"/>
                <TESTLIST_COMP tokenValue="'chserver.prod.amce'" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="14">
                  <TEST tokenValue="'chserver.prod.amce'" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="14">
                    <ATOM tokenValue="'chserver.prod.amce'" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="14">
                      <STRING tokenValue="'chserver.prod.amce'" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="14"/>
                    </ATOM>
                  </TEST>
                </TESTLIST_COMP>
                <RBRACKET tokenValue="]" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="34"/>
              </ATOM>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
        </EXPRESSION_STMT>
      </SIMPLE_STMT>
    </STMT_LIST>
    <NEWLINE tokenValue="
" tokenLine="10" tokenColumn="35"/>
  </STATEMENT>
  <STATEMENT tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
    <STMT_LIST tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
      <SIMPLE_STMT tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
        <EXPRESSION_STMT tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
            <TEST tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
              <ATOM tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
                <NAME tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0">
                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="mailDic" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="0"/>
                </NAME>
              </ATOM>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
          <ASSIGN tokenValue="=" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="8"/>
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="{" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="10">
            <TEST tokenValue="{" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="10">
              <ATOM tokenValue="{" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="10">
                <LCURLYBRACE tokenValue="{" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="10"/>
                <DICTORSETMAKER tokenValue="'John'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="12">
                  <TEST tokenValue="'John'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="12">
                    <ATOM tokenValue="'John'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="12">
                      <STRING tokenValue="'John'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="12"/>
                    </ATOM>
                  </TEST>
                  <COLON tokenValue=":" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="19"/>
                  <TEST tokenValue="'john.e@hotmail.com'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="21">
                    <ATOM tokenValue="'john.e@hotmail.com'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="21">
                      <STRING tokenValue="'john.e@hotmail.com'" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="21"/>
                    </ATOM>
                  </TEST>
                </DICTORSETMAKER>
                <RCURLYBRACE tokenValue="}" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="41"/>
              </ATOM>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
        </EXPRESSION_STMT>
      </SIMPLE_STMT>
    </STMT_LIST>
    <NEWLINE tokenValue="
" tokenLine="12" tokenColumn="42"/>
  </STATEMENT>
  <STATEMENT tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
    <STMT_LIST tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
      <SIMPLE_STMT tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
        <EXPRESSION_STMT tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
            <TEST tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
              <ATOM tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
                <NAME tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0">
                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="selection" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="0"/>
                </NAME>
              </ATOM>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
          <ASSIGN tokenValue="=" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="10"/>
          <TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR tokenValue="'mails=s%'" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="12">
            <TEST tokenValue="'mails=s%'" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="12">
              <M_EXPR tokenValue="'mails=s%'" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="12">
                <ATOM tokenValue="'mails=s%'" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="12">
                  <STRING tokenValue="'mails=s%'" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="12"/>
                </ATOM>
                <MOD tokenValue="%" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="23"/>
                <POWER tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="24">
                  <ATOM tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="24">
                    <NAME tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="24">
                      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="mails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="24"/>
                    </NAME>
                  </ATOM>
                  <TRAILER tokenValue="." tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="29">
                    <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="29"/>
                    <NAME tokenValue="Emails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="30">
                      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="Emails" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="30"/>
                    </NAME>
                  </TRAILER>
                </POWER>
              </M_EXPR>
            </TEST>
          </TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR>
        </EXPRESSION_STMT>
      </SIMPLE_STMT>
    </STMT_LIST>
  </STATEMENT>
  <EOF tokenValue="EOF" tokenLine="14" tokenColumn="36"/>
</FILE_INPUT>
```

the problem is that I want to catch the entries from the mailDic dictionary, but not from the selection.

Comment: Please show that XML data that you are trying this XPath against and what parts you are trying to find. Have a look at [mcve], which is a minimum needed for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I've added it to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> Although I get all hardcoded mails, I also get mailList, which are not hardcoded, but have qoutes in the line.

Given your input data, your current expression returns:

```
<STRING tokenColumn="12" tokenLine="12" tokenValue="'John'"/>
<STRING tokenColumn="21" tokenLine="12" tokenValue="'john.e@hotmail.com'"/>
<STRING tokenColumn="12" tokenLine="14" tokenValue="'mails=s%'"/>
```

The word "mailList" does not occur in your data, but if I assume it is in place where it currently says "mailDic", then you can fix it with this:

```
//TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR[
    contains(@tokenValue,"mail") 
    and not(@tokenValue = 'mailList')]
/..
//STRING[contains(@tokenValue,"'")]
```

If it is the `s%` from the original input that you want filtered out instead, you can use the following:

```
//TESTLIST_STAR_EXPR[contains(@tokenValue,"mail")]
/..
//STRING[
    contains(@tokenValue,"'")
    and not contains(@tokenValue, 's%')]
```

Otherwise, please update your question with input that matches your question, as it then fails the "Verifiable" from [that link I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e., I can't see what goes wrong because it goes right ;).

Comment: Do you know, if there I can loop through a list of strings?

Instead of:
//STRING[contains(@tokenValue,'a')  and contains(@tokenValue, 'b')]

I would like to do sth like this:
//STRING[contains(@tokenValue,['a','b'])]

Comment: @Krasnars, in XPath 2.0 you can do this, like `//STRING[some $tok in ('a', 'b', 'c'....) satisfies contains(., $tok)]`, in XPath 1.0, there is no such construct, so you would have to resort to XSLT if you want to do that with XPath 1.0.

Comment: Neither can I use XPath 2.0 nor can I resort XPath to XSLT, because I'm using Xpath for my SonarQube rules. But thank you for your help, I can live with my solution :).